# I am trying to categorize obervations with a variety of names by grouping them by new variables

Tags: r, arrays, associative-array

I am new to coding and have been trying to use R to simplify the management of mice for the research lab I work at.

To use mtcars as an examples.

I want to group different observations in mtcars by new variables. For example, if i wanted to group the cars by country of origin & manufacturer and year they were made, standard tire size.

More specifically for my example, i have a bunch of mice of different genotypes. There are different breeding schemes for the mice based on the genotype construct, genetic backgrounds and other factors and i want to group them by those different factors.

The problem that i currently have is that the mice that should have the same names have a range of names. So a TSLP.KO mouse, comes in the variations of TSLP-KO, TSKP.KO.B6, TSLP;KO.B6(N12F1) etc.

Lets call this DF1

```
   Mouse_ID Strain     Sex   Age_wk Genotype listgenobox DOB   Cage_ID Litter_ID Mice_Room_ID
   <fct>    <fct>      <fct>  <dbl> <fct>    <fct>       <fct> <fct>   <fct>     <fct>       
 1 ZDM862   TSLP.KO     M        6.7 ""       "_/_  _/_ ~ 12/1~ H118599 B23235-2  SZ8         
 2 ZDM863   TSLP.KO.B6  M        6.7 ""       "_/_  _/_ ~ 12/1~ H118599 B23235-2  SZ8         
 3 ZDM864   TSLP;KO     M        6.7 ""       "_/_  _/_ ~ 12/1~ H118600 B23235-2  SZ8         
 4 ZDM865   TSLP-KO     M        6.7 ""       "_/_  _/_ ~ 12/1~ H118600 B23235-2  SZ8         
 5 ZDM866   TSLP:KO     M        6.7 ""       "_/_  _/_ ~ 12/1~ H118600 B23235-2  SZ8         
 6 ZDM867   TSLPKO      F        6.7 ""       "_/_  _/_ ~ 12/1~ H118601 B23235-2  SZ8
```

My instinct was to make an excel file with the different naming variations (there are a finite number of variations) as well as the preferred nicknames and breeding scheme groups and combine that with my larger data frame that contains the Mouse ID's, Strains, Ages, Sex, Genotype etc.

Lets call this DF2

```
Breeding_Group    Preferred Name   Alternate_Name Alternate_Name2 Alternate_Name3  
   <fct>          <fct>             <fct>          <fct>           <fct>           
 1 1a             TSLP Knockout    "TSLP.KO"      "TSLP.KO.B6"      ""             
 2 2a             C57BL~           "C57BL/6"      ""                ""                          
 3 1b             CCR2.~           "CCR2.CreERT2" "CCR2-CreERT2-"   ""
```

The results im hoping for is as follows

```
 Mouse_ID Strain     Sex   Age_wk Genotype listgenobox DOB   Cage_ID Litter_ID Mice_Room_ID  Breeding_Group  Preferred Name
   <fct>    <fct>      <fct>  <dbl> <fct>    <fct>       <fct> <fct>   <fct>     <fct>         <fct>        <fct>    
 1 ZDM862   TSLP.KO     M        6.7 ""       "_/_  _/_ ~ 12/1~ H118599 B23235-2  SZ8           1a        TSLP Knockout 
 2 ZDM863   TSLP.KO.B6  M        6.7 ""       "_/_  _/_ ~ 12/1~ H118599 B23235-2  SZ8           1a        TSLP Knockout 
 3 ZDM864   TSLP;KO     M        6.7 ""       "_/_  _/_ ~ 12/1~ H118600 B23235-2  SZ8           1a        TSLP Knockout 
 4 ZDM865   TSLP-KO     M        6.7 ""       "_/_  _/_ ~ 12/1~ H118600 B23235-2  SZ8           1a        TSLP Knockout 
 5 ZDM866   TSLP:KO     M        6.7 ""       "_/_  _/_ ~ 12/1~ H118600 B23235-2  SZ8           1a        TSLP Knockout 
 6 ZDM867   TSLPKO      F        6.7 ""       "_/_  _/_ ~ 12/1~ H118601 B23235-2  SZ8           1a        TSLP Knockout
```

TL/DR 
I want to add two new variables (Preferred name & Breeding Group) to DF1 by matching the Strain names to one of the "alternate_names" variables in the DF2.

I have tried different combinations of merge() and rbind.fill() with little success.

I hope those tables are readable. I'm sorry i'm not better are framing them...yet.

Thank you in advance if you stuck with me till the end of this question. I appreciate any advice.

Comment: You should take a look at the [`forcats`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/forcats/index.html) package, it has many utility functions for recoding variables and dealing with this kind of use case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you could try using `fuzzyjoin` to merge, as names are quite close with different punctuation marks in names.

It is easier to do merge with list of different alternative names in "long" form. In this example, I adapted your data frames, use `pivot_longer` to put in long form, and then do a `fuzzyjoin`.

```
df2 %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = starts_with("Alternate"), names_to = "alt_num", names_pattern = "(\\d)$") %>%
  drop_na() %>%
  stringdist_inner_join(df1, by = c("value" = "Strain")) %>%
  group_by(Mouse_ID) %>%
  slice(1) %>%
  select(-c(alt_num, value, Strain))
```

**Output**

```
# A tibble: 10 x 5
# Groups:   Mouse_ID [10]
   Breeding_Group Preferred_Name Mouse_ID Sex   Age_wk
   <chr>          <chr>          <chr>    <chr>  <dbl>
 1 1a             TSLP_Knockout  ZDM862   M        6.7
 2 1a             TSLP_Knockout  ZDM863   M        6.7
 3 1a             TSLP_Knockout  ZDM864   M        6.7
 4 1a             TSLP_Knockout  ZDM865   M        6.7
 5 1a             TSLP_Knockout  ZDM866   M        6.7
 6 1a             TSLP_Knockout  ZDM867   F        6.7
 7 2a             C57BL~         ZDM868   F        6.7
 8 2a             C57BL~         ZDM869   M        6.7
 9 1b             CCR2.~         ZDM870   F        6.7
10 1b             CCR2.~         ZDM871   M        6.7
```

**Data**

Additional example data made up.

```
df1 <- read.table(
  text =
  "Mouse_ID Strain     Sex   Age_wk 
  ZDM862   TSLP.KO     M        6.7         
  ZDM863   TSLP.KO.B6  M        6.7          
  ZDM864   TSLP;KO     M        6.7          
  ZDM865   TSLP-KO     M        6.7          
  ZDM866   TSLP:KO     M        6.7         
  ZDM867   TSLPKO      F        6.7
  ZDM868   C57BL       F        6.7
  ZDM869   C57BL6      M        6.7
  ZDM870   CCR2        F        6.7
  ZDM871   CCR2.CreERT M        6.7", header = T, stringsAsFactors = F)   

df2 <- read.table(
  text =
    "Breeding_Group    Preferred_Name AlternateName_1   AlternateName_2 AlternateName_3 
 1a             TSLP_Knockout  TSLP_Knockout  TSLP.KO      TSLP.KO.B6                   
 2a             C57BL~         C57BL~  C57BL/6      NA                                         
 1b             CCR2.~         CCR2.~  CCR2.CreERT2 CCR2-CreERT2- ", header = T, stringsAsFactors = F)
```

Comment: This worked with some slight alteration. Thank you so much Ben!
I am well on my way to coding myself out of a job. Haha. 
No but this is really going to help me manage as many mice as i do.

Answer (score 0):

You could construct a replacement list and use a function to perform multiple substitutions, as posted here: [How to correct list of mispellings at once in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60610601/how-to-correct-list-of-mispellings-at-once-in-r/60623149#60623149)

Using your example, it would go something like this:

```
## names to replace
nn <- c("TSLP.KO","TSLP.KO.B6","TSLP;KO","TSLP-KO","TSLP:KO","TSLPKO")

## function that takes list with two elements and replaces first with second
multisub <- function(replacement.list, string, ...) {
    mygsub <- function(l, x) gsub(pattern = l[1], replacement = l[2], x, ...)
    Reduce(mygsub, replacement.list, init = string, right = TRUE)
}

## generate replacement list
mylist <- unlist(apply(cbind(nn, rep("TSLP Knockout", length(nn))), 1, list), recursive = FALSE)

## perform multiple replacement on `DF1$Strain`
DF1$`Preferred Name` <- multisub(mylist, DF1$Strain)
```